# Cannot bind to a variable declared with {#await ... then} or {:catch} blocks}

Tags: svelte

This is a nice error explanation but I don't know how to solve it.
I have a `+layout.js` that returns a `load` function async:

```js
import { api } from '$lib/utils/api';

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load() {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        return await api.auth.user();
    };

    return {
        stream: {
            user: fetchUserData()
        }
    };
}
```

Then in the `+page.svelte` I load this data with `{#await}`

```
<script>
  export let data;
  let { stream } = data;
</script>

{#await stream.user then user}
<input type="text" bind:value={user.data.gender} />
{/await}
```

Since I don't have those user data before the await finishes, I don't know how to bind it to the input if I cannot use `bind:value`. I cannot find anything from the documentation.

Comment: There shouldn't be a colon `:` here {#await stream.user then user}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the contents of the block to a separate component. I would recommend this anyway because `user` is scoped to the `{#await}` block and cannot be worked with directly in the `<script>` part otherwise.

```html
{#await ... then user}
    <UserEditor {user} />
{/await}
```

Inside `UserEditor` you then can bind as usual.

```html
<script>
    export let user;
</script>
<input bind:value={user.data.gender} />
```